# Open Stack Overflow installation/download info

Tags: support, stack-overflow, clone

You probably already know about this: [List of StackExchange 1.0 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) on Meta Stack Exchange

I've been trying to find the info I want with Google, but the number of results for the search phrase "open stackoverflow" pointing to questions here at Stack Overflow is making the search a bit hard. So, what better place to ask than here?

Where can I find information/documentation on how to install/use/extend the SO Q&A system?

I want to create a clone for a local community in my city.

Comment: There are two questions I always link to on clone-related posts: the good ones http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones and the bad ones http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/weask-us-is-cloning-stack-overflow-content

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow, Super User, Serverfault, and meta.stackoverflow are part of the Stackoverflow trilogy, and are run on one NON open source codebase.

That codebase was licensed to Fog Creek software, who are converting it into a platform for running hosted sites based on this architecture, which you can use to make your own site right now at http://www.stackexchange.com - it's free during the beta, and for 45 days thereafter (beta is still open, no official close date).  So try it out.

The codebase is not available anywhere else.

As mgb noted, there are [several other open sourceimplementations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) of the stackoverflow Q&A concept, but none are quite as complete as either stackoverflow or stackexchange.  The only instructions for installing any one of those sites would be with the maintainer(s) of the respective projects.

As the original code base is not open source, stackoverflow and fog creek are not able to support any installation or usage issues with other software.

Answer (score 1):

That is a list of sites created by customers on the official stackexchange servers hosted by stackexchange.

You can request a free site if you are a non-profit/etc/etc - but it is hosted by stackexchange, you don't get their software.

There are a few opensource stackexchange [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), but I don't have any personal experience of any of them.

ps. Should this be on meta?