# weask.us is cloning Stack Overflow content

Tags: support, copyright, attribution, copyright-infringement

Just did my usual Google search for programming stuff, and got a result from the site `www.weask.us`. To my surprise, I got a page that was ripped off Stack Overflow.

After some surfing around it became clear that they are getting all of their content from Stack Overflow and republishing with no reference to the original site.

They have built a total of three sites: `weask.us` (a Stack Overflow clone), `openg.info` (a Server Fault clone) and `gooduser.info` (a Super User clone).

Their site does not display any ads, but NoScript reports a whole bunch of JavaScript from shady URLs; you have to open a question to get the scripts.

I think the site is in clear violation of the cc-wiki license, because there is no attribution.

How do we proceed to take them down?

Comment: Add them to [the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962).

Comment: A Whois tells us that it was registered in China (via GoDaddy) a month ago...there's also an administrative address provided, but it's gmail. :/ http://www.whois.net/whois/weask.us

Comment: Shouldn't it be `weask.ourselves`? Or `weask.eachother`?

Comment: Uh, I hate those parasitic websites. Because of them, whenever I Google a problem, I often get a dozen duplicate answers, none of which work.

Comment: @mcandre - which is why I come to SO first.

Comment: I just performed a search and weask.us came up - not SO. Let's get these goons to stop. They have no attribution whatsoever. I only guessed it was an SO question because names were familiar and the OP questioning why he was getting down-voted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We now have more of a policy around this; read more about it at

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/

Comment: -1. Thats not enough. I feel betrayed by the clone page and by the community itself. File these DCMA things right away and don't ask them politly to apply to the new terms

Comment: Hmm. I understand that sending out DMCA notices would be a big thing for Stack Overflow, Inc. and needs careful proceeding, but what about us, the authors of the content? Aren't we entitled to send in notices about the specific content we created, and gave Stack Overflow permission to publish under the CC-Wiki license? Is there any resource helping with the steps, and forms, necessary to do this on an individual basis? I imagine a flood of DMCA requests coming from dozens of copyright holders is enough to stop any site in its tracks.

Comment: Well we are all part of the community. As in the original idea behind stackoverflow, the community should somehow be shaping itself. Of course that does not justify my desire (I'd guess I'm not alone with this opinion) to make the SO team taking legal actions, but nevertheless I think SO should respond with at least as twice hostile as the people behind the fake sites. As written in the SO blog, the worst part that could happen is that the community itselfs feels betrayed and stops participating in sharing intel. My advice is to act on that thought before it might get out of hands

Comment: @citronas this particular case (weask) is actually hosting malware and redirect ads which are against google's adsense TOS. I recommend filing at http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/ -- we have!

Comment: This site is getting worse, it's getting a lot of #1 hits now.  Anything else we can do?

Answer (score 4):

I just clicked on one of those `weask.us` URLs

`http://www.weask.us/entry/submitting-post-data-controller-rails-website`

and it reloaded Google ad URLs several times and then tried to use my local machine name, which just happens to redirect to port 443 (SSL) on my box.  The browser could not recognize the certificate and prompted me to accept it.  So, God knows what this site is trying to do.

Needless to say, `weask.us` is going in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Please don't link directly to sites copying content -- it only boosts their google page rank.

Comment: @Ether, good call, link removed.

Comment: @ether agreed -- also it's doing some very questionable things which are against Google's AdSense TOS .. if you have time, please file this with google at http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/ -- we have!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood- What makes this clone site very problematic is that they are getting a *higher* page rank than SO itself on certain questions.  For example, see this google search where they are the first hit while SO is # 2   http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=25901,26086,26446,26514,26549&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=Can%20I%20change%20Windows%207%20execute%20rights%20programmatically&cp=54&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=Can+I+change+Windows+7+execute+rights+programmatically&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=f42cedd875d403c4

Comment: I see SO is #1.

Comment: So basically just throw enough content at Google, scramble it up enough to "hide" that is copied and "page rank" is more or less out the window? I'm all for mixing and re-using SO content, but this site seems to be gaming Google.

Answer (score 1):

In my last job, one of our developers had to reclone their pc because weask.us uploaded some kind of virus, worm, trojan horse or who knows what.

Answer (score 0):

Added to the [list of other copy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) as suggested by Tobias.