# Another Internet site is providing Stack Overflow content and wrapping tons of advertisements around it; is this legal?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, abuse, legal, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weask.us cloning stackoverflow content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/weask-us-cloning-stackoverflow-content)

While Googling for "componentart grid search," I found this Stack Overflow question: [ComponentArt Grid OnKeyPress Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860331/componentart-grid-onkeypress-reset)

Another Google hit provided this link: `http://www.weask.us/entry/componentart-grid-onkeypress-reset`

This page uses the Stack Overflow content and wraps tons of advertisements around it (disable your ad blocker)

[image: screenshot]

Just one click away is another Stack Overflow clone: `http://www.weask.us/entry/convert-nsstring-decimal-nsstring-bytes equals` / [How to convert NSString of Decimal to NSString of Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018560) (just without the ads)

I typed my username into the search box.  It returned two results.  One of them is
`http://www.weask.us/entry/change-shortcut-lsquo-switch-markup-rsquo-visual-studio-2010`, which is the same as [Change shortcut for 'switch to markup' in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984771/change-shortcut-for-switch-to-markup-in-visual-studio-2010)

I kind of feel betrayed.  Someone is getting money for using paid linkshorteners with the knowledge I provided.

So the question is, it this legal?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/weask-us-cloning-stackoverflow-content

Comment: __Security notice about this site__: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/weask-us-cloning-stackoverflow-content/62998#62998