# Why are there so many scraper sites outranking Stack Overflow on Google?

Tags: discussion, licensing, content

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Scrapers enter the scene - was the choice of license right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71982/scrapers-enter-the-scene-was-the-choice-of-license-right)
>   [Why are clones ranking higher than Stack Overflow for questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64508/why-are-clones-ranking-higher-than-stackoverflow-for-questions-and-answers)

Why are there so many scraper sites outranking Stack Overflow on Google?

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71982